# Kendo Grid not displaying list.count

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-grid

My custom class:

```
public class StructuredUtility
{
    public string Provider { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public List<EmPemUtilityEntity> Bills { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

My Kendo Grid Widget (where Model.myUtilites is a List of StructuredUtility's):

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.myUtilities)
    .Name
        ("UtilitiesGrid")
    .Columns
        (columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(p => p.Type).Title("Type").Filterable(true).Width(250);
            columns.Bound(p => p.Provider).Title("Provider").Filterable(false).Width(100);
            columns.Bound(p => p.Bills.Count).Title("Count").Filterable(false).Width(100);                
        })
        .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar
            .Custom()
                .Text("Add New Utility")
                .HtmlAttributes(new { id = "addUtility" }))
        .Editable(editable => editable
            .Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp))
        .Pageable()
        .Sortable()
        .Scrollable(scr => scr
            .Height(430))
        .Filterable(filtering => filtering
            .Mode(GridFilterMode.Menu))
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .Model(model => model
                .Id(p => p.Id))
            .PageSize(30)
            .Read(read => read
                .Action("ReadGridEntity", "Site"))
    )
)
```

The third column in my grid is empty for all my rows. 
Digging through the HTML i found this interesting little snippet:

```
{"Provider":{"type":"string"},"Type":{"type":"string"},"Bills":{"type":"object"}
```

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion is to flatten `StructuredUtility` object to object like this:

```
public class StructuredUtilityFlat
{
    public string Provider { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public int BillsCount { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

then you can show grid for that kind of data.

Comment: This is in fact what i implemented while i waited. Thanks!